# Errors Opening FileDialog SaveAs in Outlook using VBA and Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, filedialog

I am trying to open a SAVE AS FileDialog in OUTLOOK (MS Office 2013 or 2016).  Since Outlook does not support FileDialogs, I use Excel (this seems to be the preferred approach based on dozens of searches).

I have had success opening a FilePicker dialog (msoFileDialogFilePicker) and File Open, but I just cannot get this to work for a SaveAs dialog (msoFileDialogSaveAs).

Could anyone please explain why the SaveAs does not work, but the FilePicker does.  Or, could someone explain what I am doing wrong.

Here is some sample code.  Each of These DOES Work:

```
Dim xlobj As Excel.Application
Set xlobj = New Excel.Application

Dim objDialog As FileDialog
Set objDialog = xlobj.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)  'This WORKS
Set objDialog = xlobj.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)  ' This Works too
Set objDialog = xlobj.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) ' This also works

objDialog.Show
```

HOWEVER, when I try to use msoFileDialogSaveAs I get an Error (Error -Automation Error  The remote procedure call failed).

```
Dim xlobj As Excel.Application
 Set xlobj = New Excel.Application

 Dim objDialog As FileDialog
 Set objDialog = xlobj.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) ' This throws ERROR???
```

I would welcome any ideas or onsights.

Thanks very much,

DGP

PS. In case its relevant.  The user needs to save some of their email messages in a Legal Folder.  I have built a way to Save them directly using the Sender or Recipient and a date stamp as the file name.  For this use case, they want a File Dialog so that they can manually name the File they are about to save.

Comment: SaveAs what? What are you saving?There is no workbook just the app instance. Add/Open a workbook for the application and then attempt to invoke SaveAs dialog.

Comment: We are trying to save the Outlook Message. I only use Excel because Outlook does not support FileDialog use.

Comment: To use SaveAs, you need to have a worbook open. On bare application object it will throw error. simple.

Comment: OK.  I guess that makes some sense.    Then, does anyone know how to open a SaveAs File Dialog from Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook VBA can simulate a button press with ExecuteMso.

```
Private Sub ExecuteMso_FileSAveAs()

    Dim currItem As Object

    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem

    ' Hover over the icon that you would add as a button
    ' The IdMso to use in ExecuteMso is the last part of the text displayed.
    ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("FileSaveAs")

End Sub
```

Comment: This is very interesting.  I will see if I can exploit this.  Thanks!

Comment: Niton.Thanks again for this information.  Is it possible to set the FileFolder to a specific directory when it opens?  Part of my challenge is that the Users want to be brought right to a folder which is the specific storage location for a particular legal matter.

Comment: As indicated in [CommandBars.ExecuteMso Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/commandbars-executemso-method-office) the method is for button pressing.

Comment: You could suggest a shortcut to the folder on the desktop, where the user could drag a copy of the mail.